# Java missing return statement

Tags: java, methods, return

I have the following code

```
class dog{
    String name;
    int barksLeft;
    int bark(int howManyTimes){
        while(howManyTimes >3){
            System.out.println("woff!");
            howManyTimes-=1;
            return howManyTimes;
       }
     }
}

public class implementDog{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        dog pupy = new dog();
        pupy.barksLeft = pupy.bark(6);
        System.out.println("You have "+pupy.barksLeft+" barks left");

    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get this error

```
implementDog.java:10: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
```

Here's what I checked:

- The "bark" method is not void and expects an int to be returned
- The variable being return is of type int as well
- What I want to do, is to populate the reference variable pupy.barksleft with the return value of the method, so that then I can print it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a method returning something other than void, you need to make sure that every logical path through that method explicitly returns something of the appropriate object/type. In your case, consider the situation where howManyTimes is less than or equal to 3 - it will skip the while block, and go to the end. Since there is no explicit return statement there, the method will not return anything in that situation, which is incorrect - it should return an `int` in all cases.

It should also be noted that the last statement in a non-void method should either be a `return` or a `throw`.

Comment: +1 ; strangely, your answer is the only one that actually *answers* the question, pointing out to the fact that in non-void function/method, *every path has to return something*; if you'd just mention that in such cases *the last statement in non-void method always has to be either **return** or **throw** *, it'd be perfect.

Comment: Good call with the `throw`, I added that in :)

Answer (score 2):

You should put the return statement below the `while()` loop, after it closes.  The way you've written the code, not only might it never return (e.g. if `howManyTimes <= 3` it will not go through the loop), but the method automatically exits after one iteration of the loop even when `howManyTimes > 3`.  `return` not only exits methods, it also causes the program to break out of any loops it is found in.

Answer (score 1):

Since `while(howManyTimes >3)` might never be true, you won't have any return statement in that case. You must add a return statement after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this return statement below while

```
class dog{
        String name;
        int barksLeft;
        int bark(int howManyTimes){
            while(howManyTimes >3){
                System.out.println("woff!");
                howManyTimes-=1;


            }

           return howManyTimes;
         }

    }

    public class stackof{
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            dog pupy = new dog();
            pupy.barksLeft = pupy.bark(6);
            System.out.println("You have "+pupy.barksLeft+" barks left");

        }
    }
```

Comment: you should use the regular idiom `howManyTimes--;` if you're trying to provide an actual code as an answer, not to mention you should fix the formatting/indenting of the code too.